# C++ how to Add/ find nodes on tree?? :/

Tags: c++, tree, addition, binary-search-tree

so here is part of the code, how can i ask to "add node" and have the answer added to the tree?
in this case its already set to 300 as an example. In other words how can i store the answer to a value that i can use to replace 300?  like you know when you ask a question with cout and get answer with cin

```
int main() 
{
    Tree* tree = new Tree();

    tree->addNode(300);
}
and to find node

if ( tree->findNode(300, tree->Root()) )
    cout << "Node 300found" << endl;
else
    cout << "Node 300 not found" << endl;
```

any help will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: here is the complete code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// A generic tree node class
class Node {
    int key;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    Node* parent;
public:
    Node() { key=-1; left=NULL; right=NULL; parent = NULL;};
    void setKey(int aKey) { key = aKey; };
    void setLeft(Node* aLeft) { left = aLeft; };
    void setRight(Node* aRight) { right = aRight; };
    void setParent(Node* aParent) { parent = aParent; };
    int Key() { return key; };
    Node* Left() { return left; };
    Node* Right() { return right; };
    Node* Parent() { return parent; };
};

// Binary Search Tree class (class name is Tree)
class Tree {
    Node* root;
public:
    Tree();
    ~Tree();
    Node* Root() { return root; };
    void addNode(int key);
    Node* findNode(int key, Node* parent);
    void walk(Node* node);
    void deleteNode(int key);
    Node* min(Node* node);
    Node* max(Node* node);
    Node* successor(int key, Node* parent);
    Node* predecessor(int key, Node* parent);
private:
    void addNode(int key, Node* leaf);
    void freeNode(Node* leaf);
};

// Constructor
Tree::Tree() {
    root = NULL;
}

// Destructor
Tree::~Tree() {
    freeNode(root);
}

// Free the node
void Tree::freeNode(Node* leaf)
{
    if ( leaf != NULL )
    {
        freeNode(leaf->Left());
        freeNode(leaf->Right());
        delete leaf;
    }
}

// Add a node - Time complexity is O(height of tree) on average
void Tree::addNode(int key)
{
    // If the tree has no elements (empty), add the root
    if ( root == NULL ) {
        cout << "add root node ... " << key << endl;
        Node* n = new Node();
        n->setKey(key);
        root = n;
    }
    else {
        cout << "add other node ... " << key << endl;
        addNode(key, root);
    }
}

// Add a node (private)
void Tree::addNode(int key, Node* leaf) {
    if ( key <= leaf->Key() )
    {
        if ( leaf->Left() != NULL )
            addNode(key, leaf->Left());
        else {
            Node* n = new Node();
            n->setKey(key);
            n->setParent(leaf);
            leaf->setLeft(n);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ( leaf->Right() != NULL )
            addNode(key, leaf->Right());
        else {
            Node* n = new Node();
            n->setKey(key);
            n->setParent(leaf);
            leaf->setRight(n);
        }
    }
}

// Find a node - Time Complexity is O(height of tree) on average
Node* Tree::findNode(int key, Node* node)
{
    if ( node == NULL )
        return NULL;
    else if ( node->Key() == key )
        return node;
    else if ( key <= node->Key() )
        findNode(key, node->Left());
    else if ( key > node->Key() )
        findNode(key, node->Right());
    else
        return NULL;
}

// Print the tree
void Tree::walk(Node* node)
{
    if ( node )
    {
        cout << node->Key() << " ";
        walk(node->Left());
        walk(node->Right());
    }
}

Node* Tree::min(Node* node)
{
    if ( node == NULL )
        return NULL;

    if ( node->Left() )
        min(node->Left());
    else
        return node;
}

Node* Tree::max(Node* node)
{
    if ( node == NULL )
        return NULL;

    if ( node->Right() )
        max(node->Right());
    else
        return node;
}

Node* Tree::successor(int key, Node *node)
{
    Node* thisKey = findNode(key, node);
    if ( thisKey )
        return max(thisKey->Right());
}

Node* Tree::predecessor(int key, Node *node)
{
    Node* thisKey = findNode(key, node);
    if ( thisKey )
        return max(thisKey->Left());
}
void Tree::deleteNode(int key)
{
    // Find the node.
    Node* thisKey = findNode(key, root);

    // (1)
    if ( thisKey->Left() == NULL && thisKey->Right() == NULL )
    {
        if ( thisKey->Key() > thisKey->Parent()->Key() )
            thisKey->Parent()->setRight(NULL);
        else
            thisKey->Parent()->setLeft(NULL);

        delete thisKey;
    }

    // (2)
    if ( thisKey->Left() == NULL && thisKey->Right() != NULL )
    {
        if ( thisKey->Key() > thisKey->Parent()->Key() )
            thisKey->Parent()->setRight(thisKey->Right());
        else
            thisKey->Parent()->setLeft(thisKey->Right());

        delete thisKey;
    }
    if ( thisKey->Left() != NULL && thisKey->Right() == NULL )
    {
        if ( thisKey->Key() > thisKey->Parent()->Key() )
            thisKey->Parent()->setRight(thisKey->Left());
        else
            thisKey->Parent()->setLeft(thisKey->Left());

        delete thisKey;
    }

    // (3)
    if ( thisKey->Left() != NULL && thisKey->Right() != NULL )
    {
        Node* sub = predecessor(thisKey->Key(), thisKey);
        if ( sub == NULL )
            sub = successor(thisKey->Key(), thisKey);

        if ( sub->Parent()->Key() <= sub->Key() )
            sub->Parent()->setRight(sub->Right());
        else
            sub->Parent()->setLeft(sub->Left());

        thisKey->setKey(sub->Key());
        delete sub;
    }
}

// Test main program
// For the Assignment, you make this Menu Driven
int main() {
    Tree* tree = new Tree();

    // Add nodes
    tree->addNode(300);
    tree->addNode(100);
    tree->addNode(200);
    tree->addNode(400);
    tree->addNode(500);

    // Traverse the tree
    tree->walk(tree->Root());
    cout << endl;

    // Find nodes
    if ( tree->findNode(500, tree->Root()) )
        cout << "Node 500 found" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Node 500 not found" << endl;

    if ( tree->findNode(600, tree->Root()) )
        cout << "Node 600 found" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Node 600 not found" << endl;

    // Min & Max
    cout << "Min=" << tree->min(tree->Root())->Key() << endl;
    cout << "Max=" << tree->max(tree->Root())->Key() << endl;

    // Successor and Predecessor
    cout << "Successor to 300=" <<
        tree->successor(300, tree->Root())->Key() << endl;
    cout << "Predecessor to 300=" <<
        tree->predecessor(300, tree->Root())->Key() << endl;

    // Delete a node
    tree->deleteNode(300);

    // Traverse the tree
    tree->walk(tree->Root());
    cout << endl;

    delete tree;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `Tree` and its methods won't implement themselves! Where are they coming from, and what policies/properties do they have? :D

Comment: Do you have any Tree implementation to be shown? What kind of Tree is this?

Comment: Use a 'std::set<int>' instead.

Comment: Wow, that amended code is just too much. Could you please simplify it to strip the irrelevant parts?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use STL?

Answer (score 0):

```
void Tree::insert(int data)
{
return insert( data, root );
}

void Tree::insert(int data, Node *&node)
{
if( node == 0 )
{
    node = new Node(data);
}
else
{
    if( data > node->getData() )
        return insert( data, node->getRight() );
    else
        return insert( data, node->getLeft() );
}
 }
```

Comment: The OP already had a tree implementation, and it is not necessarily the same requirement as yours.